# Pass Firebase user across multiple widgets Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

After logging in to my app, I can pass the user to my Home widget like this...

```
Future checkAuth(BuildContext context) async {
    FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
    if (user != null) {
      print("Already singed-in with ${user.email}");
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home(user)));
    }
  }
```

In Home widget, I take the argument like this
**Edit** IfI moved my `tabs` inside Build, It just doesn't work. Maybe because I use bottom navigation?

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  final FirebaseUser user;
  Home(this.user, {Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  final tabs = [
    Container(
      child: FirestoreSlideshow(),
    ),
    Container(
        child: ProfilePage(widget.user), //Got an error on this line
    )
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: tabs[_currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        selectedFontSize: 15,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.home,
                size: 28.0,
              ),
              title: Text('Home')),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.account_circle,
              size: 28.0,
            ),
            title: Text('Profile'),
          ),
        ],
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            _currentIndex = index;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And in ProfilePage widget, I take the argument just like in Home

```
class ProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final FirebaseUser user;
  ProfilePage(this.user, {Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _ProfilePage createState() => _ProfilePage();
}
```

But I keep getting this error

```
Only static members can be accessed in initializers.
```

I tried to solve this for a while but none of the posts seems to answer my question.
How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use widget.user in initstate.

```
var tabs;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tabs = [
      Container(
        child: FirestoreSlideshow(),
      ),
      Container(
        child: ProfilePage(widget.user), //Got an error on this line
      )
    ];
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Passing something like a User object, which is generally something your whole app should be aware of isn't the best idea. You should look into a more structural solution, I recommend using the Provider pattern. Making the user accessible from any widget in your app.

Jeff Delaney (Fireship.io) has a great video on this subject which you might want to check out.

https://fireship.io/lessons/advanced-flutter-firebase/

Answer (score 1):

You have to call "ProfilePage(widget.user)" in the build method.
You cannot access the user variable in a variable declaration like you do here:

```
final tabs = [
    Container(
      child: FirestoreSlideshow(),
    ),
    Container(
        child: ProfilePage(widget.user), //Got an error on this line
    )
  ];
```

do:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context){
return Container(
            child: ProfilePage(widget.user),
        );
}
```

Comment: See update, please. PS. I only need to get email form user (user.email) so maybe I should pass only the string?

Comment: @BookTeeranai if you only need email, you can just pass the email, but you need to initialize the tabs variable in the build method or in the initState method.